# global variables used in a gitlab pipeline not working

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, yaml, pipeline

Problem: I am trying to get gloabal variables to work within gitlab. My understanding was that one needed to create a `central variable file` and then use it across all of the other files.

In the file `*gitlabfiles/variables.yml*`, I created a `variable file` and initialized the variables. In the `*gitlabfiles/.gitlab-extract-tag-values.yml*`  the varaibles are assigned and in the `*gitlabfiles/.gitlab-merge-sap-into-dev.yml*`, the assigned values are reference.

**The problem is:  they do not get assigned at all**. They are just blank ( or perhaps they are null or undefined ). Either way, the variables assigned in the yml file  `*gitlabfiles/.gitlab-extract-tag-values.yml*`  are not present

**Question:** How can one get this functionality to work ( or does it work at all?)

TIA

**gitlabfiles/variables.yml**

```
variables:
    TARGET_BRANCH: ""
    TARGET_TAG: ""
    TARGET_TAG_EXISTS: ""
    SOURCE_TAG: ""
    SOURCE_TAG_EXISTS: ""
    VALID_SOURCE_GEN_ABSENT_TAG: ""
    SOURCE_GEN_ABSENT_TAG: ""
    VALID_SOURCE_SLDC_TAG: ""
    SOURCE_SLDC_TAG: ""
    VALID_SOURCE_TAG_EXISTS_ON_BRANCH: ""
```

In the second file below, the variables ( in the variables.yml file ) get assigned.

**gitlabfiles/.gitlab-extract-tag-values.yml**

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && ($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "dev" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "test" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "stage" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "prod")'

include:
    - gitlabfiles/variables.yml

stages:
    - extract_tag_values

job_1:
  stage: extract_tag_values  # Removed the colon here

  tags:
    - simba
    - bash
    - small

  script:
    - TARGET_BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
    - |
      exit_code=$?
      if [[ $exit_code -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo "Error: generation of target branch failed with exit code $exit_code"
        exit 1
      fi

[ ... snip ...]
```

In the third file below, the variables get accessed - but the problem is that they are blank. My understanding was that when one defined global variables this way, they would be accessible across all of the yml files. The file below uses variables defined in the **gitlabfiles/variables.yml**

**gitlabfiles/.gitlab-merge-sap-into-dev.yml**

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && ($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "dev")'

    
include:
    - gitlabfiles/variables.yml

stages:
    - merge_sap_into_dev

job_2:
  stage: merge_sap_into_dev  # Removed the colon here

  tags:
    - simba
    - bash
    - small

  script:
      # the source branch MUST have a VALID tag before it can be
      # passed to Jenkins
    - |
      JENKINS_TAG=""
      if [ "$SOURCE_TAG_EXISTS" == false ]; then

      [ ... snip ...]

      elif  [ "$VALID_SOURCE_TAG_EXISTS_ON_BRANCH" == true ]; then
          if [ "$VALID_SOURCE_SLDC_TAG" == true ]; then
            JENKINS_TAG=$SOURCE_SLDC_TAG  
          elif [ "$VALID_SOURCE_GEN_ABSENT_TAG" == true ]; then
            JENKINS_TAG=SOURCE_GEN_ABSENT_TAG
          else
            echo "invalid tag type for target dev branch => $SOURCE_TAG"
            echo "Remove tag from the branch and try again"
            exit 1
          fi
      fi

      if [ "$JENKINS_TAG" == "" ]; then
        echo "Error => Jenkins tag was never assigned "
        echo "VALID_SOURCE_TAG_EXISTS_ON_BRANCH => $VALID_SOURCE_TAG_EXISTS_ON_BRANCH "
        echo "VALID_SLDC_TAG  => $VALID_SLDC_TAG "
        echo "VALID_SOURCE_GEN_ABSENT_TAG  => $VALID_SOURCE_GEN_ABSENT_TAG "
        exit 1
      fi
 
      echo "call Jenkins with this tag JENKINS_TAG => $JENKINS_TAG   MESSAGE => $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE"
```

the file below is the .gitlab-ci.yml file

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
workflow:
  rules:
    # code changed so that it works with MERGE EVENTS ONLY!
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && ($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "dev" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "test" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "stage" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "prod")'

include:
  - gitlabfiles/variables.yml
  - gitlabfiles/.gitlab-extract-tag-values.yml
  - gitlabfiles/.gitlab-merge-sap-into-dev.yml

# new test - making the change
stages:
  - extract_tag_values
  - merge_sap_into_dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab variables dont work the way you are trying to use. If global variables are set in one job, they wont retain the value in another job. Script section in each job only inherits the values assgined(initialized) in the global "variables" section.

To acheive what you are looking for you need to use **"artifacts:reports:dotenv"**

The dotenv report collects a set of environment variables as artifacts from a job(in your case job1). And using the "needs" keyword the artifact is downloaded in the dependent job(job2) and is injected into the environment of job2

Get rid of the variables.yml as we dont need this. We will have to export the variable values set in job 1 as an artifact and inject that into the environment in job2.

Here is a high level example

**gitlabfiles/.gitlab-extract-tag-values.yml**

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && ($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "dev" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "test" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "stage" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "prod")'

stages:
    - extract_tag_values

job_1:
  stage: extract_tag_values  # Removed the colon here
  tags:
    - simba
    - bash
    - small
  script: |
    # set you variables here and put them into variables.env file
    # example I am setting only two of your variables with hardcoded values 
    # This is just a demonstration, you can set them dymamically anyway you want to
    TARGET_BRANCH="dev"
    TARGET_TAG="1.0.0"

    # append the variables to a ".env file"
    echo "TARGET_BRANCH=$TARGET_BRANCH" >> variables.env
    echo "TARGET_TAG=$TARGET_TAG" >> variables.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: variables.env
```

**gitlabfiles/.gitlab-merge-sap-into-dev.yml**

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && ($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "dev")'
stages:
    - merge_sap_into_dev
job_2:
  stage: merge_sap_into_dev  # Removed the colon here
  tags:
    - simba
    - bash
    - small
  needs: [job_1]
  stage: merge_sap_into_dev  # Removed the colon here
  script: |
    echo $TARGET_BRANCH
    echo $TARGET_TAG
```

The echo out put in job2

```
dev
1.0.0
```

So now the variables set in job1 are accessible in job2

Answer (score 0):

To reuse variables the way you want to do it, using `include`, it's probably best to make use of hidden jobs and then `extend` from it whenever you need them. With this strategy you can carry repetitive information from one job to another without having to use `artifacts` which seems to be a bit of an overkill. With these changes, your files will look like this:

**gitlabfiles/variables.yaml**

```yaml
.env-vars:
    variables:
        TARGET_BRANCH: ""
        TARGET_TAG: ""
        TARGET_TAG_EXISTS: ""
        SOURCE_TAG: ""
        SOURCE_TAG_EXISTS: ""
        VALID_SOURCE_GEN_ABSENT_TAG: ""
        SOURCE_GEN_ABSENT_TAG: ""
        VALID_SOURCE_SLDC_TAG: ""
        SOURCE_SLDC_TAG: ""
        VALID_SOURCE_TAG_EXISTS_ON_BRANCH: ""
```

And then on any of your files that you wish to use them, simply add this job to `extends` and you're ready to go, e.g:

**gitlabfiles/.gitlab-extract-tag-values.yaml**

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && ($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "dev" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "test" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "stage" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "prod")'

include:
    - gitlabfiles/variables.yml

stages:
    - extract_tag_values

job_1:
  stage: extract_tag_values  # Removed the colon here
  extends: .env-vars
  tags:
    - simba
    - bash
    - small

  script:
    - TARGET_BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
    - |
      exit_code=$?
      if [[ $exit_code -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo "Error: generation of target branch failed with exit code $exit_code"
        exit 1
      fi

[ ... snip ...]
```

Also in the last of the CI files, you won't need to include the env vars file, as you don't seem to be using them and the other two CI files already have that dependency added:

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    # code changed so that it works with MERGE EVENTS ONLY!
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && ($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "dev" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "test" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "stage" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "prod")'

include:
  - gitlabfiles/.gitlab-extract-tag-values.yml
  - gitlabfiles/.gitlab-merge-sap-into-dev.yml

# new test - making the change
stages:
  - extract_tag_values
  - merge_sap_into_dev
```

Comment: The problem statement here is not reusability(by using extends), rather on how environemnt values set in one stage can be used in the other. Your solution still does not address how this is possible.